# Atlanta Sitecore User Group - June 28, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Date/Time (EST):** Wednesday, June 28, 2017, 6:30 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Wednesday, June 28, 2017, 23:30

**Location:** [Roam Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us), 3365 Piedmont Rd NE, Suite 1400, Atlanta, GA

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/240110904/

**Twitter:** [@AtlantaSitecore](https://twitter.com/atlantasitecore)

[image: Atlanta Sitecore User Group]

Mark your calendars for the next [Atlanta Sitecore User Group](https://www.meetup.com/Atlanta-Sitecore/events/240110904/) meeting on June 28, at 6:30 pm, at [Roam in Buckhead](https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=3365+Piedmont+Rd+NE,+Suite+1400,+Atlanta,+GA,+us)!

The theme of this quarter's meeting will be focusing on case studies from [Global Payments](https://www.globalpaymentsinc.com/en-us) and [Iron Mountain](http://www.ironmountain.com/). Shaun Baddock of [Global Payments](https://www.globalpaymentsinc.com/en-us) will be presenting on their Sitecore brand framework that they use to manage all of their distinct brands and local market websites.

Heath Morton, of [Iron Mountain](http://www.ironmountain.com/) will be presenting on their journey with Sitecore, lessons learned, current use, and future vision.

Additionally, [Corey Smith](https://twitter.com/sitecorey) of [Perficient](https://twitter.com/Perficient_MSFT) will provide everyone a recap of the recent SUGCON Europe event.

Parking will be complimentary. We will be providing prepaid validations to all of our guests.

Looking forward to seeing everyone!

Comment: UTC times, please

Comment: I have added the event. It will appear in the sidebar 10 days in advance.